# Support closing of a NSWindow presented as sheet via escape key

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, interface-builder

How do I setup an NSWindows (on OS X) to be closed when the user presses the escape key?

- The window is presented as a sheet via
  `presentingWindow.beginSheet(mySheetWindow, completionHandler:nil)`
- It has a close button (via IB) that has a key equivalent set to 'escape'. This close button is already working
- Pressing escape leads to the system audio error output ('Funk' - Sound), but no logging and no closing of the window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You  have to add a regular button and position it at the top left corner of your window. Set your button  width and alpha  to 0.

[image] [image]

Click at the key equivalent field and press ESC. It will show the escape key icon

[image]

Then create your IBAction for the hidden button as follow:

```
@IBAction func closeWindowAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    window.close()
}
```

Make sure you have your window outlet connected to the proper window:

```
@IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. Unfortunately that doesn't help because the window is not presented as a sheet. It's just the main window. The main window should present another window using `beginSheet(newWindow, completionHandler:nil)` and this newWindow should be closable via escape key.

Comment: I found the solution myself... In my case I needed to subclass NSWindow, override **canBecomeKeyWindow** and return true. Otherwise it didn't work!

Comment: Yes - that was my question. I have (already had it) a NSButton with the title 'Close' that has a key equivalent set to 'escape'. Due to the fact that the window couldn't become the keyWindow pressing escape lead to the audio error output. It's working now. Thank you for assisting me!