# How to capture escape key in an NSWindow?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsviewcontroller, nsevent, nsresponder

I've got a storyboard with an NSWindowController (the storyboard entry point), whose content is an NSViewController.  When the user selects a menuitem in my application, I load the storyboard and display it.

Now I want the "escape" key to close the window.  I've seen several questions about this, but none that matches the behavior I'm seeing.

I subclassed NSWindowController and NSViewController, and set the controllers in the storyboard to those.  I've tried [every method I could find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42393336/how-to-close-window-nswindowcontroller-by-hitting-the-esc-key) or think of, including:

- `override func cancelOperation(_ sender: Any?)`
- `func cancel(_ sender: Any?)`
- `override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent)`

in the window controller, the view controller, and even a custom NSWindow subclass, but none of these methods get called.  I've confirmed that `viewDidLoad()` and `windowDidLoad()` do get called, so my classes are getting used.  They're just not getting events.

To verify my sanity, I tried [inspecting the responder chain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42146694/7656954).  [As expected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35558378/7656954), both my custom window controller and view controller classes are in it, as is the NSWindow subclass.

Why would an NSResponder object in the responder chain not receive events?

Comment: Inspired by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28739846, I tried setting the "Key Equivalent" of a button on my view to escape (⎋), but no luck.  I also tried more typical keys, like command-A, but no luck there, either.

Comment: Which view is first responder when you hit the escape key? Any custom views who catch keydown events?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622255/keydown-not-being-called. You need to make sure your window can become the main window and the key window and that is NOT a borderless window.

Comment: jvarela: Bingo!  Adding "Title bar" to its appearance fixes it.  Or overriding `canBecomeKey`.

Answer (score 1):

```
// monitor ESC key
NSEvent* (^handler)(NSEvent*) = ^(NSEvent *event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 53) {
        [self keyDown:event];
    }
    return event;
};
eventMonitor = [NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSKeyDownMask handler:handler];
```

Put these code into a NSWindowController or AppDelegate class.